# Address in Turkey eVisa

Tags: turkey, e-visas

My current address which happens to be permanent address is different from the address in my passport. Which address should I mention while filling in the address details for a Turkey eVisa?

Comment: Give your current address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure not all passports contain their user's address (eg mine does not) and frankly I am a bit surprised any bother to, if they do. With many passports lasting 5 to 10 years there seems little point, given the chances of a move of home over such a period. Driving licences seem a somewhat different case (mine does show my address and there are quite severe penalties for not keeping it up to date).

My passport does have space for an address – twice over (ie two of them) but that is for assistance with communicating with someone concerned in case of an emergency, for which my own address in either slot might not make much sense.

So, as stated by @edocetirwi:

> Give your current address

Apart from anything else, where else would you want to be contacted in case of issues with your eVisa (that could not be handled by email)?